# Remove duplicates while keeping NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data that looks like the following:

```
a<-data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","C",NA,NA),score=c(1,2,3,3,5,6),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
print(a)
ID score
A     1
B     2
C     3
C     3
<NA>  5
<NA>  6
```

I am trying to remove duplicates without R treating `<NA>` as duplicates to get the following:

```
b<-data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C",NA,NA),score=c(1,2,3,5,6),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
print(b)
ID score
A     1
B     2
C     3
<NA>  5
<NA>  6
```

I have tried the following:

```
b<-a[!duplicated(a$ID),]
library(dplyr)
b<-distinct(a,ID)
print(b)
```

But both treat `<NA>` as a duplicate `ID` and remove one, but I want to keep all instances of `<NA>`.  Thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: @d.b If these were the only two columns (there are more in the data) it could be the case that multiple `<NA>` s in ID have the same score and I wouldn't want those removed.

Comment: `a[!duplicated(a),]` should work. Duplicated function does the rest

Comment: @Onyambu this is the same issue as mentioned above.

Comment: @costebk08 Look carefully, the above uses the function `duplicated(a$ID)` rather than `duplicated(a)`

Comment: @Onyambu yeah unfortunately the solution doesn't work because it looks across all of the variables in `a`.  Basically I am looking for something that says remove duplicate obervations while ignoring `NA` for just one variable.

Comment: @costebk08 just extend the condition then `a[!(duplicated(a$ID)&!is.na(a$ID)),]`

Comment: @Onyambu There are like 100 variables, so coding it like this would not be feasible.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks. Hope the answer given helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straight forward approach is to break the original data frame down into 2 parts where ID is NA and where it is not.  Perform your distinct filter and then combine the data frames back together:

```
a<-data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","C",NA,NA),score=c(1,2,3,3,5,6),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

aprime<-a[!is.na(a$ID),]
aNA<-a[is.na(a$ID),]

b<-aprime[!duplicated(aprime$ID),]

b<-rbind(b, aNA)
```

With a little work, one can reduce this down to a 1-2 line lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

using dplyr:

```
   b%>%group_by(ID,score)%>%distinct()


# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   ID, score [5]
     ID score
  <chr> <dbl>
1     A     1
2     B     2
3     C     3
4  <NA>     5
5  <NA>     6
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I have other variables, which I don't want to include in the group.  Also, even if these were the only two columns it could be the case that multiple `<NA>` s in `ID` have the same `score` and I wouldn't want those removed.

Answer (score 1):

Found a very simple way to do this simply using the base duplicated() function.

```
b<-a[!duplicated(a$ID, incomparables = NA),]
```

Setting incomparables = NA makes R read NA duplicates as FALSE, therefore including them in the result dataset.